# Reverted BIOS to default, now don't have GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, lenovo

I have a lenovo laptop with Windows 10. Some time later I installed Ubuntu on this laptop and could choose whether I wanted to use Windows or Ubuntu from GRUB. Today something strange happened, I turned on my PC as usual, but instead of GRUB menu I saw Lenovo Boot Manager with options Windows, Ubuntu and HDD, all of them sent me back to this Boot Manager.

I went to BIOS and set all settings to default. After that Lenovo finally loaded, but I don't have GRUB, Windows is just loaded like Ubuntu was't installed at all.

How can I restore GRUB or at least delete it together with Ubuntu to reinstall them later?

Comment: You have  UEFI, not BIOS. By resetting it probably selected Windows again. Please check whether or not you can select Ubuntu as that will give the Grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good step by step for installing/repairing GRUB: https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Note that you'll need a live CD and you'll need to know which partition Ubuntu is installed on (you can find this out using gparted from the live CD).

Here is a brief summary of the steps that are described at length in the link above (note - replace sdXY with your Ubuntu partition):

```
# mount the Ubuntu partitions
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt

# mount the directories that GRUB needs
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

# make Ubuntu the root partition
sudo chroot /mnt

# now install grub (note that this time use the device name, not the partition name
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub

# Done! Now just the clean up and then reboot...
exit
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt
```